# About the tie in card game 'Le Her'

Tags: probability, card-games

I am analyzing a game called 'Le Her', some of you will be known to be a classic card game in the calculus of probabilities at the times of Bernoulli and Montmort. But I have a question about the game, and I don't know if it really is because the rules that normally describe them are ambiguous or basically the game is like that.

I will write the rules based on the document [Le Her and Other Problems in Probability Discussed by Bernoulli, Montmort and Waldegrave](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.01950.pdf):

> Montmort calls the two players Pierre and Paul. Pierre deals a card from the deck to Paul and then one to himself. Paul has the option of switching his card for Pierre’s card. Pierre can only refuse the switch if he holds a king (the highest valued card). After Paul makes his decision to hold or switch, Pierre now has the option to hold whatever card he now has or to switch it with a card drawn from the deck. However, if he draws a king, he must retain his original card. The player with the highest card wins the pot, with ties going to the dealer Pierre

The problem I have is the tie part, is it in the case when the two players get to get cards of the same value, or is it only in the case that they both get Kings? If someone knows the game well, please let me note about this, i will really appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: By 'tie', do you mean the case when both players' initial draw is that of a King?

Comment: I think it must mean the case where both players hold a card of the same value, for otherwise, no rule is given to determine the result when both hold $7$ says.

Comment: Sorry for not responding to your comments. Now I understand the game well, because I was not clear that the Dealer should deliver the cards to the players, make the respective card changes and then the game ends seeing who got the card with the highest value, I thought that the game should continue delivering more cards until there were no more. With all of the above clearly stated, it makes sense that a tie occurs when the players get the same values on their cards. Thanks you for your comments.